# Photo / video theatre mode

Tags: facebook, lightbox

When a user clicks a photo in their photo album, or even on their wall, Facebook overlays a lightbox of the image at larger dimensions complete with Like link and comments box.

Is there an API, maybe using UI Dialogs, that we can use to put this functionality in to our Facebook canvas apps or Mobile URL websites?

My understand is that this functionality is **not** available to us as developers - an understanding that comes from searching around on Google, on FB and one or two similar questions here on SO (albeit from last year). If possible i'd just like some up-to-date confirmation that this is still the case because FB changes every 5 minutes these days...

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to close and accept my own answer as I still believe my assertion of it **not** being possible is correct.